Use Bayesian PyMC linear model on out-of-sample data
I am trying to fit a linear model to data using Bayesian inference technique. For this, I thought of using PyMC. Naturally, after training a model, I want to test its performance on new data and that's where the problem occurs. I don't seem to be able to set a new dataset. Anybody with experience?
Example script that shows the error:
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def run_model():
    # Generate synthetic data
    np.random.seed(42)
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    a_true = 2.5  # True slope
    b_true = 1.0  # True intercept
    y_true = a_true * x + b_true
    y = y_true + np.random.normal(0, 1, size=x.size)  # Add some noise

    # Split into training and test sets
    x_train, x_test = x[:80], x[80:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:80], y[80:]

    # Define and fit the model
    with pm.Model() as linear_model:
        # Define x as a pm.Data variable to allow updating with pm.set_data
        x_shared = pm.Data("x", x_train)

        # Priors for slope and intercept
        a = pm.Normal("a", mu=0, sigma=10)
        b = pm.Normal("b", mu=0, sigma=10)
        sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1)

        # Expected value of y
        mu = a * x_shared + b

        # Likelihood
        y_obs = pm.Normal("y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=y_train)

        # Sample from the posterior
        trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000, return_inferencedata=True, chains=1)

    # Predict on training data
    with linear_model:
        pm.set_data({"x": x_train})  # Update data to training
        post_pred_train = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace)

    # Predict on test data
    with linear_model:
        pm.set_data({"x": x_test})  # Update data to testing
        post_pred_test = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace)

    # Plot results
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

    # Plot training data
    plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, c="blue", label="Training data")
    plt.plot(x_train, y_true[:80], "k--", label="True function")

    # Plot posterior predictive for training data
    plt.plot(
        x_train,
        post_pred_train["y_obs"].mean(axis=0),
        label="Posterior predictive (train)",
        color="red",
    )

    # Plot test data
    plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, c="green", label="Test data")

    # Plot posterior predictive for test data
    plt.plot(
        x_test,
        post_pred_test["y_obs"].mean(axis=0),
        label="Posterior predictive (test)",
        color="orange",
    )

    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.title("Bayesian Linear Regression with PyMC")
    plt.show()

    # Summary of the model parameters
    print(az.summary(trace, var_names=["a", "b", "sigma"]))


# Only execute if run as the main module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_model()

Error that results:
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (80,) and arg 1 with shape (20,).
Apply node that caused the error: normal_rv{"(),()->()"}(RNG(<Generator(PCG64) at 0x1F23323B5A0>), [80], Composite{((i0 * i1) + i2)}.0, ExpandDims{axis=0}.0)
Toposort index: 4
Inputs types: [RandomGeneratorType, TensorType(int64, shape=(1,)), TensorType(float64, shape=(None,)), TensorType(float64, shape=(1,))]
Inputs shapes: ['No shapes', (1,), (20,), (1,)]
Inputs strides: ['No strides', (8,), (8,), (8,)]
Inputs values: [Generator(PCG64) at 0x1F23323B5A0, array([80], dtype=int64), 'not shown', array([0.97974278])]
Outputs clients: [[output[1](normal_rv{"(),()->()"}.0)], [output[0](y_obs)]]


This blog post allowed me to figure out the answer, so credit mostly goes there and I would recommended you read it in full.
The key point is that you need to include the shape argument in your definition of y_obs:
y_obs = pm.Normal("y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, shape=x_shared.shape, observed=y_train)

Note the shape=x_shared.shape !
I also saw in multiple examples (the blog and the pymc docs) that you should do
post_pred_test = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, predictions=True)

i.e. set predictions=True - not sure if this makes a big difference but it seems like the right thing to do...
Your code has some other issues, at least with my version of pymc:
You cannot do post_pred_train["y_obs"].mean(axis=0), but I got it working with
plt.plot(
    x_train,
    post_pred_train.posterior_predictive["y_obs"].mean(("chain", "draw")),
    label="Posterior predictive (train)",
    color="red",
)

and similarly (but confusingly slightly different), for the test data:
plt.plot(
    x_test,
    post_pred_test.predictions["y_obs"].mean(("chain", "draw")),
    label="Posterior predictive (test)",
    color="orange",
)

Note: .predictions here instead of .posterior_predictive
And in both cases, I needed to take the mean across chain and draw
